# Python coding technique: class methods that use another method as interface to do system calls

Tags: python, python-decorators

Is there a way to better implement my code leveraging python coding techniques considering that I have a few methods that are all wrapping one specific method and adding a bit of pre/post processing to it?

Looking to leverage python coding techniques (thinking python decorators might help clean this a bit) to implement the class below.

I have a class that has one method to interface with the outside world and that other methods in the class use to execute actions and do pre/post processing of some data.

```
import subprocess as sp


class MyClass():

    def _system_interface(self, command):
        hello = ["echo", "'hello'"]
        start = ["echo", "'start'"]
        stop = ["echo", "'reset'"]
        reset = ["echo", "'reset'"]

        cmd = sp.Popen(locals()[command], stdout=sp.PIPE)
        output = cmd.stdout.readlines()
        print(output)
        return cmd.stdout.readlines()

    def call_one(self):
        # Do some processing
        self._system_interface("hello")

    def call_two(self):
        # Do some processing
        self._system_interface("start")

    def call_three(self):
        # Do some processing
        self._system_interface("stop")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        c = MyClass()
        c.call_one()
        c.call_two()
        c.call_three()
```

Comment: What  is the question?

Comment: This question is better suited for CodeReview.SE. Note though that you shouldn't be using `locals()` like that; rather, store your commands as a dict.

Comment: @Vlad Is there a way to better implement my code leveraging python coding techniques considering that I have a few methods that are all wrapping one specific method and adding a but adding a bit of pre/post processing to it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks. Could you expand on why shouldn't use `locals()`?

Comment: Because like I say, this is exactly what a dict is for. There's no point polluting the namespace with extra names, then using a hack to look them up, when you could define a single name in an appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class that takes a command when instantiated, and when called, returns a decorator function that calls `Popen` with a command derived from the command given during the instantiation:

```
import subprocess as sp

class system_interface:
    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            cmd = sp.Popen(['echo', self.command], stdout=sp.PIPE)
            output = cmd.stdout.readlines()
            print(output)
            return cmd.stdout.readlines()

        return wrapper

class MyClass():
    @system_interface('hello')
    def call_one(self):
        print('one: do some processing')

    @system_interface('start')
    def call_two(self):
        print('two: do some processing')

    @system_interface('stop')
    def call_three(self):
        print('three: do some processing')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = MyClass()
    c.call_one()
    c.call_two()
    c.call_three()
```

This outputs:

```
one: do some processing
[b'hello\n']
two: do some processing
[b'start\n']
three: do some processing
[b'stop\n']
```

Comment: Awesome! I think this is what I was looking for.
It seems like I would have to either do pre or post processing around the system call. Is there a way to do both or probably just have to wrap that around another function?

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you need to performing both pre- and post-processing then your original approach of having a common worker method would be the best, since decorators are meant to wrap around the decorated functions, not the other way around.